# Multithreading in sbcl

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am newbie at programming in lisp.I am using sbcl.In one part of program thread is created as-

```
(sb-thread:make-thread
  (lambda ()
    (progn
      (sleep 0)
      (setf c (+ a b))
      (print "ADDITION:")
      (print c))))
```

I am not getting what `lambda()` and `progn(sleep 0)` does, and why it is written inside `sb-thread` bracket?

Answer (score 6):

`sb-thread:make-thread` takes a function to call in a newly created thread.

```
(lambda ()
   (progn
      (sleep 0)
      (setf c (+ a b))
      (print "ADDITION")
      (print c)))
```

is an anonymous function. In turn `progn` creates a program block (un-necessarily in this case, as a lambda body is an implicit progn) and `(sleep 0)` is probably used as a "please invoke the scheduler here" (it's essentially a no-op, sleeping for 0 seconds).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use the REPL, to experiment with Lisp Code is the best way for learning, for your code,  If you use SBCL I recommend you to develope using slime

I reccomend you to try this on the REPL:

```
; first define the parameters that you will use inside the tread
CL-USER> (defparameter a 3)
A
CL-USER> (defparameter b 4)
B
CL-USER> (sb-thread:make-thread
  (lambda ()
    (progn
      (sleep 0)
      (setf c (+ a b))
      (print "ADDITION:")
      (print c))))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: C
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     C
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
#<SB-THREAD:THREAD RUNNING {1003CD34A3}>

; put the tread inside a lisp variable like this
CL-USER> (defparameter my-thread (sb-thread:make-thread
  (lambda ()
    (progn
      (sleep 0)
      (setf c (+ a b))
      (print "ADDITION:")
      (print c)))))

; in: DEFPARAMETER MY-THREAD
;     (SETF C (+ A B))
; ==>
;   (SETQ C (+ A B))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: C
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     C
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
MY-THREAD
; the REPL says you that the variable C is unbound for this if you want you may initialize it
CL-USER> (sb-thread:join-thread my-thread )
7
CL-USER>
```

On your question the function (sleep n) sleeps the current thread, or stopping working for n seconds in your case 0 seconds.

Lambda comes from lambda calulus, is the way of defining functions that doesnt have a name, this is good for things like this when you need to pass an easy and short function as a parameter

finally progn is a lisp special form that allows you to execute several common lisp expressions and returns the result of the last expression

I also want you to check the basics from here [sb-threads basics](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Threading-basics)